# Jquery Onclick and reference to the object clicked

Tags: jquery, click

I've got the following jQuery expression, Inside the function I need a reference to the object that was clicked, is there a way to do this?

```
$('#tagList li').click(function() {
  /* contents */
});
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use

```
$(this)
```

Answer (score 10):

you can use the return value

```
$("#tagList li").bind("click", function(e) {
    alert(e.currentTarget + ' was clicked!');
});
```

or if you want, you can simple point to the object in jQuery mode

```
$("#tagList li").bind("click", function(e) {
    alert($(this) + ' was clicked!');
});
```

if you're new to jQuery, **I strongly suggest** you to see some screencasts from **[Remy Sharp](http://twitter.com/rem)** in **[jQuery for Designers](http://www.jqueryfordesigners.com)**, they are great to understand a little bit of how jQuery works, and better yet, how to use the **console.log()** in order to see the objects that you can use!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the `this` keyword references the DOM element that was clicked.  You can "wrap" it like this:

```
$(this)
```

This will allow you to treat it as a jQuery object.

Answer (score 6):

The *this* keyword is what you are looking for. Often you will want to apply the jQuery function to *this* to do your job. Example:

```
$('#tagList li').click(function() {
  $(this).css({ color: 'red' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new answer that will cover more use cases, specifically when you want to use arrow functions.

It's also recommended that you don't add a JS click to an li element. Instead you should use a button or anchor (something clickable) nested inside this element.

Since the element that you click could be a child, you need to make sure you target the correct element.

In my example, I will be assigning the click to a button inside the li as well as a class on it. The markup will simply be:

```
<ul id="taglist">
  <li><button class="tag-button">Tag 1</button></li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Then the javascript:

```
$('#tagList li button.tag-button').click((e) => {
  const thisButton = $(e.target).hasClass('tag-button')
    ? $(e.target) : $(e.target).closest('.tag-button');
  // do something with thisButton
});
```

This ensures that you are targeting the element that the click was registered on. If you have any nested markup inside your button (such as  or ) then it is possible for the event target to be the nested element rather than the element you wanted to assign the click to.